# How do I write a Rails finder method where none of the has_many items has a non-nil field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many, finder

I'm using Rails 5.  I have the following model ...

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

The LineItem model has an attribute, "discount_applied."  I would like to return all orders where there are zero instances of a line item having the "discount_applied" field being not nil.  How do I write such a finder method?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Is it using "raw" SQL an option?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. So you want essentially all Orders where the LineOrders associated have a discount_applied of nil?

Comment: @bwalshy, I want all orders that have no line items where a discount_applied field is not nil.  This would include orders with no line items, orders with a single line item where discount_applied is nil, or orders with two line items where both discount_applied fields are nil, or orders with three line items ... I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not efficient but I thought it may solve your problem:

```rb
orders = Order.includes(:line_items).select do |order|
  order.line_items.all? { |line_item| line_item.discount_applied.nil? }
end
```

**Update**:

Instead of finding orders which all it's line items have no discount, we can exclude all the orders which have line items with a discount applied from the output result. This can be done with *subquery* inside where clause:

```rb
# Find all ids of orders which have line items with a discount applied:
excluded_ids = LineItem.select(:order_id)
                       .where.not(discount_applied: nil)
                       .distinct.map(&:order_id)

# exclude those ids from all orders:
Order.where.not(id: excluded_ids)
```

You can combine them in a single finder method:

```rb
Order.where.not(id: LineItem
                    .select(:order_id)
                    .where.not(discount_applied: nil))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for this @Mosaaleb -- the logic seems to work as I test it out.  Regarding the update you made, any way to combine those two things into a single finder method?

Comment: Hi @Dave. Yes sure you can combine them, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this really depends on whether or not you want to use a pure Arel approach or if using SQL is fine. The former is IMO only advisable if you intend to build a library but unnecessary if you're building an app where, in reality, it's highly unlikely that you're changing your DBMS along the way (and if you do, changing a handful of manual queries will probably be the least of your troubles).

Assuming using SQL is fine, the simplest solution that should work across pretty much all databases is this:

```rb
Order.where("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM line_items WHERE line_items.order_id = orders.id AND line_items.discount_applied IS NULL) = 0")
```

This should also work pretty much everywhere (and has a bit more Arel and less manual SQL):

```rb
Order.left_joins(:line_items).where(line_items: { discount_applied: nil }).group("orders.id").having("COUNT(line_items.id) = 0")
```

Depending on your specific DBMS (more specifically: its respective query optimizer), one or the other might be more performant.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using PostGres but is there any way to make this RDBMS neutral?

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous answer for clarity: Both of my examples should work in all DBMS which are SQL-compliant – but they might not run in the most optimized way because Arel sometimes does magic things under the hood to re-arrange queries for individual DBMS. For Postgres, in my experience it doesn't matter because its query optimizer is smart enough to do its job either way.

Comment: Oh gotcha @ClemensKofler -- yeah the SQL you have looks standard to me and performance doesn't matter at this stage.  One question, in the solutions you have above, where do you take account of the constraint that all discount_applied fields from the LineItems must be nil?

Comment: I've added the conditional to both flavors. Note that I haven't tested this and it's just typed down from knowledge of how it _should_ work.

Answer (score 0):

A possible code

```
Order.includes(:line_items).where.not(line_items: {discount_applied: nil})
```

I advice to get familiar with AR documentation for Query Methods.

#### Update

This seems to be more interested than I initially though. And more complicated, so I will not be able to give you a working code. But I would  look into a solution using `LineItem.group(order_id).having(discount_applied: nil)`, which should give you a collection of line_items and then use it as sub-query to find related orders.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working.  It's returning results where an Order will have some line items with a discount_applied field of nil and non-nil.  Ideally the only orders that shoudl be returned should have all line items with discount_applied being nil.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. That part about zero instances was not clear to me.

Comment: No worries, thanks for giving it a shot and including the update for my further thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get all orders for which none line item (if any) has a discount applied.

One way to get those orders using `ActiveRecord` would be the following:

```
Order.distinct.left_outer_joins(:line_items).where(line_items: { discount_applied: nil })
```

Here's a brief explanation of how that works:

- The solution uses `left_outer_joins`, assuming you won't be accessing the line items for each order. You can also use `left_joins`, which is an alias.
- If you need to instantiate the line items for each `Order` instance, add `.eager_load(:line_items)` to the chain which will prevent doing an additional query for every order (N+1), i.e., doing `order.line_items.each` in a view.
- Using `distinct` is essential to make sure that orders are only included once in the result.

**Update**

My previous solution was only checking that `discount_applied IS NULL` for at least one line item, not all of them. The following query should return the orders you need.

```
Order.left_joins(:line_items).group(:id).having("COUNT(line_items.discount_applied) = ?", 0)
```

This is what's going on:

- The solution still needs to use a left outer join (`orders LEFT OUTER JOIN line_items`) so that orders without any associated items are included.
- Groups the line items to get a single `Order` object regardless of how many items it has (`GROUP BY recipes.id`).
- It counts the number of line items that were given a discount for each order, only selecting the ones whose items have zero discounts applied (`HAVING (COUNT(line_items.discount_applied) = 0)`).

I hope that helps.

Comment: What is "steps" supposed to be?  The above gives the error 'missing FROM-clause entry for table "steps"'

Comment: I am sorry @Dave that was a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Np @SebastianSogamoso, but this doesn't seem to be quite working.  This, 'Order.distinct.left_outer_joins(:line_items).where(line_items: { discount_applied: nil }).select{|o| o.line_items.any?{ |li| li.discount_applied != nil }}.count' returns a number greater than zero.  If all the found orders had only line items with discount_applied being nil, I believe my statement should return zero.

Comment: @Dave that's right. I missed that initially so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the records where discount_applied is nil then:

`Order.includes(:line_items).where.not(line_items: {discount_applied: nil})`

(use includes to avoid n+1 problem)
or

```
Order.joins(:line_items).where.not(line_items: {discount_applied: nil})
```

Comment: Hi, This was also the answer submitted above by @adass, however it fails because it returns Orders that have at least one line item with a non-nil discount_applied whereas I'm only looking for Orders with all LineItems having discount_applied being non-nil (or Orders with no LineItems at all).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem

```
order_ids = Order.joins(:line_items).where.not(line_items: {discount_applied: nil}).pluck(:id)
orders = Order.where.not(id: order_ids)
```

First query will return ids of `Orders` with at least one `line_item` having `discount_applied`. The second query will return all `orders` where there are zero instances of a `line_item` having the `discount_applied`.

Comment: Thanks, but how is this solution different than the one offered by Mosaaleb above?

Comment: My bad, I missed that answer, Mossaleb's answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `NOT EXISTS` feature from SQL, which is at least available in both MySQL and PostgreSQL

it should look like this

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  scope :without_discounts, -> {
    where("NOT EXISTS (?)", line_items.where("discount_applied is not null")
  }
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this efficiently with a classic rails left_joins, but sql left join was build to handle thoses cases

```
Order.joins("LEFT JOIN line_items AS li ON li.order_id = orders.id 
                                       AND li.discount_applied IS NOT NULL")
     .where("li.id IS NULL")
```

A simple inner join will return all orders, joined with all line_items,
but if there are no line_items for this order, the order is ignored (like a  false where)
With left join, if no line_items was found, sql will joins it to an empty entry in order to keep it

So we left joined the line_items we don't want, and find all orders joined with an empty line_items

And avoid all code with `where(id: pluck(:id))` or `having("COUNT(*) = 0")`, on day this will kill your database